# How to create a line in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a horizontal line underneath my nav bar, the only problem is that the line breaks. How do I get the line to go all the way across the page? I tried using border and using hr is the closest I can get to what I want but I need it to go all the way across.

HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <style>
    body {
       margin:0;
       padding: 0;
       font-family: "Open+Sans", sans-serif;
    }


    #nav {
        background-color: #fff; 
        color: white;
        width: 100%;

    }
    .nav {
      float: right;
        text-align: left;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .nav > li {                                                             
        display:Inline-block;
        padding: 20px 50px 10px 9px;                              
    }

     .nav > li a {                                               
         text-decoration: none;
         color: #0C133C;
         font-size: 18px;

     }
    hr.solid {
      border-top: 2px solid #0C133C;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

<ul class="nav justify-content-end">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Get a Quote</a>
  </li>
<li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link active"aria-current="page" href="#">Contact Us</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link active"aria-current="page" href="#">Sign In</a>
  </li>
 
<hr class="solid">  
 
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX8Rk.png)

Comment: how about putting `hr` after `ul` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well. wish add this css in your styles.css and remove the hr tag can solve ur problem

```css
.nav {
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.nav::after{
    content: '';
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    bottom: 2px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul class="nav justify-content-end">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Get a Quote</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Sign In</a>
      </li>

      <!-- <hr class="solid" /> -->
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

normally i will do like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Open+Sans", sans-serif;
}
.nav {
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}
/* new css here */
.nav-bar {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0c133c;
}
.clearfix::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
/* new css here */

.nav > li {
  display: Inline-block;
  padding: 20px 50px 10px 9px;
}

.nav > li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0c133c;
  font-size: 18px;
}
hr.solid {
  border-top: 2px solid #0c133c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"
  </head>

  <body>
      <!-- add a father element -->
    <div class="nav-bar clearfix">
        <ul class="nav justify-content-end">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Get a Quote</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Sign In</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Comment: you are welcome! but i my opinion this may cause some style problem.if u want to create a underline in you nav bar without using flex. normally i will doing this way---i will update to my answer

Comment: @nmart Okay i think the answer of fir3chi3f is clearer than mine hh

Answer (score 3):

Just a few things holding you back here.

Think of every element on the page as a box first we need to make sure your boxes are the well organized before we can decorate them.

You've got a tiny box `nav` which is floating right on the page. It's tiny because it's an `inline` element. We need a big long box to cover the entire top of the page first and the `nav` element can be inside that one.

For our big box we want to use a block element like `div`. We decorate the big box with the `border-bottom` attribute including the width and color to get the bar we want.

**There is another catch.** Because you're floating right it will reorg the page and make a mess. We need a way to clear the float after. Notice the clearer div added to the snippet

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Open+Sans", sans-serif;
 }

 .navbar {
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
 }
 
 
 #nav {
     background-color: #fff; 
     color: white;
     width: 100%;
 
 }
 .nav {
   float: right;
     text-align: left;
   margin: 0;
 }
 .nav > li {                                                             
     display:Inline-block;
     padding: 20px 50px 10px 9px;                              
 }
 
.nav > li a {                                               
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0C133C;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}
.clearer {
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Navbar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Get a Quote</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Sign In</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearer"></div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use from **flex** instead float:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Open+Sans", sans-serif;
}

#nav {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav>li {
  display: Inline-block;
  padding: 20px 50px 10px 9px;
}

.nav>li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0C133C;
  font-size: 18px;
}

hr.solid {
  border-top: 2px solid #0C133C;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Navbar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" </head>

  <body>

    <ul class="nav justify-content-end">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Get a Quote</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Sign In</a>
      </li>

      <!-- <hr class="solid"> -->

    </ul>

    <hr class="solid">
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The typical browser sets the margin to roughly half a character's width. But you can change this to any value you want. This can add quality white space to your layouts and emphasize the content break.

```
hr
 {
width: 80%;
height: 8px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color:#666;
border: 0 none;
margin-top: 100px;
margin-bottom:100px;
}
```